# GTalk ("Google Talk") Windows Desktop Client to be discontinued on February 16, 2015. Hangouts Alternatives?

Tags: chat, xmpp, google-hangouts

GTalk will stop working on Feb 16, 2015.

[image]

**Google Says** to start using the Hangouts Chrome App. I don't like it. Is there any third party or open source alternative to the Chrome app (for Windows) that lets me talk to my google contacts? From what I understand, google moved away from the XMPP protocol so third-party development is no longer possible. Does this mean programs like pidgin can no longer talk to hangouts people on Feb 16, or does pidgin still somehow connect?

I just want to use something as simple and featureless as GTalk. I hate Hangouts.

Comment: Unfortunately that will most likely be not possible. The Hangout stuff is google proprietary and I have not yet seen anybody interested in porting that to Pidgin or any other floss client (which are the only ones I care about). So, I would recommend to go over to jabber.org make an account there and convince your fellow GTalk users to do the same. Then you can use Pidgin and have a regular chat. (Note: I have not seen anybody does not mean that there is nobody, just that I have not yet seen them)

Comment: GTalk is now really shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that **[Miranda](http://www.miranda-im.org/)** lets you still login to the old GTalk network and talk to your google contacts. It doesn't support voice chat, but has a minimalist interface just like GTalk did. There is also [Miranda NG](http://www.miranda-ng.org/en/) but I found that interface too bloated like all the other IM clients out there.

When installing, setup a "JABBER" account and put your gmail username (everything before the "@" sign). Then you need to go to **Accounts** and set the "type" of Jabber connection to "**GTalk!**" and fill in your info like the pic below:

[image]

After filling in your account info, make sure you set your "*status*" to online (or invisible) and your buddy list will be downloaded.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: You **have to enable "*[less secure apps](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/21/gmail-starts-block-less-secure-apps-enable-access/)*"** in your Google Account if you want to use Miranda!!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/xmikos/qhangups is a PyQt application, that is a GUI interface to the command-line client at https://github.com/tdryer/hangups, that was created by reverse-engineering the undocumented Hangouts API.

It doesn't seem to work for me but seems promising. I would like to see it gain momentum, contributors etc.

Answer (score -1):

With my personal experience of what I am using right now is [Trillian](https://www.trillian.im/download/) and this also works like a email client.*And in my opinion this is even better than Google talk

I will list down some features from its official website and few screenshots
for your reference.

This is available as [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) and paid

[image: The right Trillian for your: Free, Pro, Lifetime]

> #### Features
>
> - Continuous Client
>   Your chats go with you everywhere. Trillian even keeps your phone quiet when you're active at a desktop!
> - Interoperable
>   With support for Google Talk, Facebook, MSN, AIM, ICQ, Yahoo!, and more, stay connected with everyone.
> - Device Support
>   **Trillian is available on Windows, Mac, iPhone, iPad, Android, BlackBerry, and directly in your web browser.**
> - Email
>   POP3, IMAP, and native IM mail integration. New mail alerts and basic mail management are all exposed.
> - Social
>   Never miss a beat with Trillian's social integration, keeping you connected to Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn.
> - Tabbed Chats
>   Keep your desktop tidy with tabbed chats, featuring drag and drop support, unread indicators, and more.
> - Message History
>   All desktop versions of Trillian come with a fully-featured message history viewer, including searching and filters.
> - Spellcheck
>   Trillian's integrated spellcheck will always let you know when a word is misspelled and offer suggested fixes.
> - Emoticons
>   Hundreds of amazing handcrafted emoticons for your chatting pleasure. Find them all, even the hidden ones!
> - […]
> - Internationalization
>   User-created language packs and strong UTF-8 support help ensure a great experience in your native language.

[image: Welcome to Trillian: Set up Instant Messaging]

**Contacts**

[image: Screenshot of contact list]

Note: To use any version of Trillian you'll have to have your own Trillian Account (formerly "Astra Account"), which keeps your settings synchronized between Trillian on your desktop, mobile devices and in-browser Trillian for Web which also another feature.

Hope my answer will help you to get out of *Hangouts Chrome App* ;)